# Python input file containing commands to be executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am working on an exercise where I am creating Python 3 functions that create and modify a stack, built upon Python lists. My function names include: `createstack()`, `pop()`, `push()` etc. 
Is it possible to create an input text file that contains a succession of commands that will execute the various functions? The structure of my code currently is:

```
def createstack():
.
.
def pop(stackin,data):
.
.
.
def push(stackin,data):
.
.
.
#main
```

I can test the functions by coding, for example, `push(stack3,"dog")` in the main section of the code.
Can I achieve the same testing by putting the `push`, `pop`, `createstack` etc. in a file and somehow my routine can read the file then execute each line as if it was in the main part of my Python module?

I am developing and running the code using IDLE.

Comment: I see 2 ways: 1. With `eval` 2. You make another python executable, where you import the first python file with necessary functions and call them

Comment: Hello Andrew, For option 2 do you mean something like .. create a new "harness" module where import crlstack is at the top of the "harness" - the effect being import "brings in" the source code containing my push(), pop(), createstack(), etc.? Then in the "harness" I code: stack1 = createstack(), stack1 = push(stack1,"dog)? As a side issue, if my imported module was written as a class, the syntax of the call in the "harness" would be: stack1.push("dog") ?

Comment: DO NOT use `eval`. It's unsafe and there are much better solutions.

Comment: Yeah, import "brings in" the code written in the imported module, as you could see in the tutorial given in the answer. Next question: well, it depends on how exactly do you import it. If like this `from crlstack import createstack, ...` then yes, but if like just `import crlstack` - no, you will have to call `crlstack.createstack()`. The least way of importing reduces the risk of a naming conflict

Comment: Last question: you mean, like, Stack class was defined in the imported module? Then you will first have to create an instance of the class by calling `stack1 = [crlstack.]Stack(...)`, after that you will be able to invoke any methods of that class like `stack1.push(...)`

Comment: To round this off I created a module, crlstack.py, that contains the stack functions I wrote: `pop( ), push ( )` (no OO just yet). Then in my "calling module", test-harness.py, the first line is `import crlstack`. When I invoke the stack operations in test-harness, they are all prefixed crlstack. e.g. `crlstack,pop()`. It works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look to this tutorial, you should and can import your file from other python files:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules

Comment: It looks like (as in Andrew Che's comment above), import is a very "clean" way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely ! I just wanted to point you to a full explanation that could help you to have a broader understanding

Answer (score 0):

As they said the proper way of doing this is importing the module and run it as a regular python file, buy if you really want a plain text file, you can make some kind of toy language like:

```
push, "dog"
push, 3
push, False
pop
pop
```

And then do something to parse it:

```
from mystack import createstack, push, pop

class MyLangParser:
    COM_POP = "POP"
    COM_PUSH = "PUSH"

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = createstack()

    def push(self, val):
        push(self.stack, val)

    def pop(self):
        return pop(self.stack)

    def parse(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            self.parse_line(line)
            print(self.stack)

    def parse_line(self, line):
        try:
            command, val = line.split(",")
            if command.strip().upper() == self.COM_PUSH:
                self.push(eval(val.strip())) # I don't like this, but it is the easiest (most dangerous) way.
            elif command.strip().upper() == self.COM_POP:
                self.pop()
            else:
                raise SyntaxError("Command not recognized")
        except ValueError:
            if line.strip().upper() == self.COM_POP:
                self.pop()
            else:
                raise SyntaxError("Command not recognized")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = MyLangParser()
    parser.parse(sys.argv[1])
```

With the previous example, and the following functions

```
def createstack():
    return []

def push(alist, val):
    alist.append(val)

def pop(alist):
    return alist.pop()
```

the output is:

```
['dog']
['dog', 3]
['dog', 3, False]
['dog', 3]
['dog']
```

I hope that with this you recognize that the proper way of doing this is importing the module from other python file.